# Getting information from website and displaying in UITableView

Tags: xcode, xmlhttprequest, xml-parsing

I want to get information from website and display it in a UITableView.

http://www.uhhospitals.org/rainbowchildren/HealthInformation/SymptomChecker/AbdominalPain.aspx 
is the website I am trying to access.

In the Symptom Description tab page, Definition is a section in table view and causes is another section.

In the 'should I call' tab page,I want each of the conditions(points) to be listed in a cell and the their heading would be titleForHeader for that section.

Initially I was manually storing all the data in different tables and I was trying to access them. I was really excited to find this website. Now I am clueless how to use the data in my application. Any idea on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

If there is any tutorial that I can read and understand, it will really help (I could not hit on a proper one). I read that I could do xml parsing but I am not sure where to find API for this page.

Thanks!